# How do I print only the first page of a website using ExecWbin VBA?

Tags: html, excel, vba, printing

I am trying to print out a website, but I only need page 1. To clarify, this webpage prints out across anywhere from 2-5 sheets of paper because the length of it changes depending on what is requested from it. I want to only print out what would be on the first sheet of paper.

```
With Application
    prin = .ActivePrinter
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

    tick = Range("A" & I).Value

    ie.navigate "website.can't show real one"
    Do While ie.Busy
    Loop
    Do While ie.readyState <> 4
    Loop

    ie.ExecWB 6, 2
    .Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:08"))
    ie.Quit
End with
```

I don't know how to format the ExecWB function to have it select a specific page to print. 6 means OLECMDID_PRINT and 2 is to not prompt the user.